# beginner | threadPool | printout every result | wrong result

Tags: java, threadpool

i tried to add 1 to "global counter" by every Thread. So the result of "global counter" must be 10.
I printout every thread result. Most time the last result is 10. but some time the 10 is not the last number. I used synchronized or lock, but its not working.

Thank you. I hope my english is not too bad.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Hauptprogramm {

public static final int MAX_THREADS = 10;
public static int globalCounter;

public static void main(String[] args) {

 // create a pool of threads, 10 max jobs will execute in parallel
 ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREADS);

 // submit jobs to be executing by the pool
 for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
   threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
       // some code to run in parallel
       globalCounter++;


        String originalName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
       System.out.println("Result: "+globalCounter+"  "+originalName);


       try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);

       } catch (InterruptedException e) {

       }

     }
   });
 }
   threadPool.shutdown();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Print the output in the question

Comment: the result is random. like this: Result: 5           pool-1-thread-1
Result: 6  pool-1-thread-6
Result: 5  pool-1-thread-4
Result: 5  pool-1-thread-2
Result: 5  pool-1-thread-3
Result: 5  pool-1-thread-5
Result: 7  pool-1-thread-7
Result: 8  pool-1-thread-8
Result: 9  pool-1-thread-9
Result: 10  pool-1-thread-10

Comment: That's an expected result without synchronisation.

Comment: this is correct output, also I like nuts

Comment: What do you want to achieve from this program

Comment: Can you add what you tried for synchronisation and in what way it "did not work"? You mentioned having tried "lock" and "synchronized".

Comment: but its not working when i use lock.lock(); and lock.unlock(); where do i need to put it? the 10 is not always the last right result.

Comment: I suggest you start with a `synchronized` block. Using `Lock`s has pitfalls you do not want to deal with when sarting out learning concurrency. From the class's name I guess you are german speaking. You might find reading "[Java ist auch eine Insel](http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel/)" helpful. Especially chapter 12.5.4 "Kritische Abschnitte schützen"

Comment: An alternative would be using an [AtomicLong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) or AtomicInteger. But I guess this is about learning how to sync and how to "detect" what a critical block is.

Comment: Yes i will do it now, but is my code really correct? Im not sure.Dont i need callable?

Comment: Ya your code is correct. but what do u wnat to achieve from the progarm

Comment: i want add +1 to global counter. when i have 10 Threads it should be 10. Then i want to show the result of every thread. Like 1, 2 , 3,4,5....10 (the 10 must be the last one, the other are random ofc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wandered what has been expected from this test, as I don't have 50 reputation yet, I can not add comments.

Java thread is running in JVM where there's no control in resource allocation from high level, if you are inquired to have thread that start execution after another, use release-lock mechanism, but there's no guarantee that it will do sequentially, if you inquired to do it sequentially you need to do some logic for recognition of what thread required to be executed after one another.

Comment: i added synchronized (Hauptprogramm.class) {...} Is this enough? the result is now 1 2 3 4 5...10. seems too easy

Comment: It was happen to be sequential because it execute sequentially by loop and synchronized block, this case the thread is not execute sequentially. you may see the other result when you swap the interruption before the global counter.

but if this is the expected result, then it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is right now:

```
            public void run() {
                synchronized(Hauptprogramm.class)
                  {


                globalCounter++;

                String originalName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                System.out.println("Result: " + globalCounter + "  " + originalName);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }

                  }
            }});
        }

    threadPool.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: Actually, that would be a poor choice of synchronization scope. You want to keep synchronized blocks as small as possible ( but as long as needed ). Think: What is the critical resource here? - globalCounter. So you should only sync the part where globalCounter is in use. As is, the thread will never have concurrent parts (or better nearly none), so you could have as well incremented the counter on one thread only.

Comment: @Fildor But its not working when i dont synchronize the try-catch part too